# Substitution cipher in Java. Only encodes when written in uppercase

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, substitution, case-insensitive

```
public static String EncodeString(String message, String subcode) { 
    message.toUpperCase();
    subcode.toUpperCase();
    
    boolean valid = true;
    if(subcode.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+") && subcode.length()==26) {
        for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j<26; j++){
                if(subcode.charAt(i)!=subcode.charAt(j)) {
                    valid = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    valid = false;
                    
                    
    if(message.isEmpty() || subcode.isEmpty()) {
        return "Error";
    }
    
    String encryptedString = "";
    
    char[] alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    char[] sub = subcode.toCharArray();
    
    for (int k = 0; k < message.length(); k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 26; l++) {
            if (message.charAt(k) == alpha[l]) 
            {
                encryptedString += sub[j];
                break;
            }

            // if there are any special characters
            // add them directly to the string
            char input = message.charAt(i);
            if (message.charAt(i) < 'A' && message.charAt(i) > 'Z' || message.charAt(i) > 'a' && message.charAt(i) < 'z'); 
            {
                encryptedString += message.charAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return encryptedString.toUpperCase();
    
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I've written this code for a substitution cipher in Java. It takes a message and a substitution code in and then encrypts the message using the substitution code. However the substitution code has to pass some checks such as being 26 letters in length and no repeated letters, though when i run this code nothing happens after the subcode checks. Another thing that I'm having an issue with is that the message only encodes when it is written in uppercase, as you can see I've tried to make it so that both uppercase and lowercase letters encrypt however this doesn't work, I'm not quite sure how to make it case insensitive.

Comment: `toUpperCase` *returns* an upper-cased string; it does not modify strings in-place. I'd start there.

Comment: Java strings are immutable. The first thing one must learn on Java strings.

Answer (score 0):

To make your method case insensitive you need to change the first two lines of your method to

```
message = message.toUpperCase();
subcode = subcode.toUpperCase();
```

As stated in the documentation for the String class: "Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created". The String.toUpperCase() method does not mutate the String, it returns a new String with all characters as uppercase.
Also, your code for checking if there are duplicate characters does not seem correct. You should not use a `break` when the compared character are different. I am guessing you meant to have this in the other branch of that if statement. Here is a simplified version of your duplicate check:

```
if(subcode.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+") && subcode.length()==26) {
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j<26; j++){
            if(subcode.charAt(i) == subcode.charAt(j)) {
                // duplicate character, not allowed
                return "Error";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above you can delete the `valid` boolean since any duplicate character will cause the method return.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! But it now says that the code underneath this is unreachable, not sure why thats happening

Comment: This means that it is impossible to reach the code beneath, but that should not be the case from my suggested code change since the return statement is only reached under certain circumstances. Could you share the current status of your code, or perhaps a link to your source code?

Comment: Sorry it works now but the lowercase message still doesn't encode, it only returns the message in an uppercase format. I think its because of the special character checker but I've tried to change that as seen in the code above.

Comment: In your example above the returned String will always be uppercase because you are returning `encryptedString.toUpperCase();`. Also, you might not want to change `subCode` to upperCase since you build your encrypted string from it and that will your program to append uppercase characters.